# Sumar columnas con la funcion SUM SQL, realiza la suma pero al doble del valor esperado

Tags: sql

**Hola tengo la siguiente sentencia, lo malo es que me esta sumando el doble, por ejemplo al ejecutarla me arroja los siguientes valores:**

1|prueba|x|x|168|92|2|8

**Me tendría que estar devolviendo algo así**

1|prueba|x|x|84 |46|1|4

```
SELECT
    proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest,
    proyecto.NombreProyecto,
    total_casos_disenados.Estado,
    complemento.Estado AS Ejecucion,
    SUM(total_casos_disenados.Total_Casos) AS SUM_DISE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN total_casos_disenados.Estado ='Passed' THEN total_casos_disenados.Total_Casos ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_PASSED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN defectos_proyecto_estado.Estatus = 'Closed' THEN defectos_proyecto_estado.Total ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_CLOSED,
    SUM(defectos_proyecto_estado.Total) AS SUM_ESTADO
FROM
    proyecto
    INNER JOIN total_casos_disenados ON proyecto.NombreProyecto = total_casos_disenados.NombrePRoyecto
    INNER JOIN complemento ON proyecto.NombreProyecto = complemento.NombreProyecto
    INNER JOIN defectos_proyecto_estado ON proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest =defectos_proyecto_estado.IDProyectoSpiraTest
WHERE
    proyecto.NombreProyecto = total_casos_disenados.NombreProyecto
    AND proyecto.Activo = 1
    GROUP BY proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest
    ORDER by proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer los `INNER JOIN` están agregando más registros y por eso se duplican las sumas; por lo tanto podrías intentar hacer los `SUM` antes de los `JOIN`.

Además, es importante notar que necesitas también agrupar por `total_casos_disenados.Estado` de lo contrario los datos no serán correctos (i.e. te mostrará el total de todos los elementos de `Estado`, pero únicamente verás la primer etiqueta).

Considerando lo anterior, tu query debería verse así:

```
SELECT
    proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest,
    proyecto.NombreProyecto,
    total_casos_disenados.Estado,
    complemento.Estado AS Ejecucion,
    SUM_DISE,
    SUM_PASSED,
    SUM_CLOSED,
    SUM_ESTADO
FROM
    proyecto INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        NombreProyecto,
        Estado,
        SUM(Total_Casos) AS SUM_DISE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Estado = 'Passed' THEN Total_Casos ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_PASSED
     FROM total_casos_disenados
     GROUP BY NombreProyecto, Estado
    ) total_casos_disenados
    ON proyecto.NombreProyecto = total_casos_disenados.NombreProyecto INNER JOIN
    complemento
    ON proyecto.NombreProyecto = complemento.NombreProyecto INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        IDProyectoSpiraTest,
        SUM(Total) AS SUM_ESTADO,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Estatus = 'Closed' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_CLOSED
     FROM defectos_proyecto_estado
     GROUP BY IDProyectoSpiraTest
    ) defectos_proyecto_estado
    ON proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest = defectos_proyecto_estado.IDProyectoSpiraTest
WHERE
    proyecto.NombreProyecto = total_casos_disenados.NombreProyecto AND
    proyecto.Activo = 1
GROUP BY
    proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest, total_casos_disenados.Estado
ORDER BY
    proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest;
```

En caso que quieras mantener el comportamiento de estado como estaba (i.e. obtener todos pero bajo la misma etiqueta), realiza estos dos ajustes:

1. Cambia `total_casos_disenados.Estado,` en `SELECT` por `MAX(total_casos_disenados.Estado) AS Estado,`:

   ```
   SELECT
       proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest,
       proyecto.NombreProyecto,
       total_casos_disenados.Estado,
       complemento.Estado AS Ejecucion,
       SUM_DISE,
       SUM_PASSED,
       SUM_CLOSED,
       SUM_ESTADO
   ```
2. Borra `, total_casos_disenados.Estado` de `GROUP BY`:

   ```
   GROUP BY
       proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest
   ```

Comment: Listo no pude subir toda la informacion, espero y sirva. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e2e7/1

Comment: @CarlosBaez Al parecer los datos son insuficientes pues el resultado de tu query me trae 0, ¿podrías agregar más información para lograr reproducir el error? Decidí utilizar [rexter](http://rextester.com/OWAI9286) en lugar de sqlfiddle ya que estaba muy lento (en la liga ya está el esquema con los datos que habías puesto en sqlfiddle).

Comment: Gerry tengo preparado la DB, espero y este link si sirva, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.
http://rextester.com/HNTBD84798

Comment: @CarlosBaez Listo, checa la respuesta actualizada, en particular presta atención al tema de `Estado`, pues puede generarte resultados incorrectos.

Comment: @CarlosBaez No pude seguir probando en _rextester_ pues me cortaba el proceso (por la cantidad de datos), pero tome el esquema y tuve el resultado correcto haciendo pruebas locales.

Comment: Gerry, lamentablemente no puedo puntuar a tu respuesta pero ambas alternativas que me siguieres funcionan a la perfección, muchas gracias por la atención y la ayuda brindada

Comment: @CarlosBaez Ya has aceptado la respuesta, gracias. Suerte!